# Prevent DIV container from getting under floated menu

Tags: html, css, position

I have a DIV which will contain the content for a website of mine. On the left side there is a menu which has its position set to `float`. When I re-size my browser the container gets under the box and it looks quite bad.

This is how it looks like:
[image: Bad look]

I have tried to put all the relevant HTML and CSS in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dugi/qZ67C/

How would I make the DIV container have itself getting smaller against the floating menu and not get under it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the .container to float left, and then increase the `margin-left` until it is out from under it.  You could also shrink the width of the .container.  Both worked while I was playing with the fiddle, but you'll have to adjust your table.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/qZ67C/3/), with .container floated left, and a `margin-left` big enough to slide it out.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/qZ67C/4/), with a smaller .container width.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is that you have percentage width on `.sidebar`, but also a min-width.

One solution is to place a min-width on `.outer`. This will prevent `.content` from slipping under `.sidebar.` as it down-sizes, but will cause `.outer` to overflow the viewport and induce a scrollber when the viewport is sized below 750 (minus .outer margin) pixels.

Here's your fiddle with the simple change of setting min-width on `.outer` to 750px: http://jsfiddle.net/qZ67C/5/